# Scrollviewer not visible inside Usercontrol WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, prism

WPF Scrollviewer not visible inside Usercontrol.

I am using PRISM architecture.

I have a scrollviewer inside usercontrol and the scrollviewer contains a stackpanel.

```
<UserControl x:Class="SomeView"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"        
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"        
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"         
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"         
      mc:Ignorable="d" >

     <UserControl.Resources>        
     <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>        
     </UserControl.Resources>

     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">  
     <StackPanel>     
<TextBlock Text="Initialize" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

 <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">     
 <Label Content="Left"/>     

 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding LeftComboItems}"  SelectedItem="{Binding LeftSelectedItem}" />　
 <Label Content="Right"/>     
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RightComboItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding RightSelectedItem}"/>     
 <Label/>    

<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"/>     
 </StackPanel>     
 <StackPanel Visibility="{Binding IsVisible,Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">   

 <Grid>
```

Skipping column definitions

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">     
 <Label Content="Left"  />     
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding LeftDataGrid}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Column="2" >     
 <DataGrid.Columns>     
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" />     
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />     
 </DataGrid.Columns>     
 </DataGrid>     
 </StackPanel>  

 <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">   
 <Label Content="Left Grid" />     
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding RightDataGrid, Mode=OneWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" >


 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding id}" />     
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>     

 </DataGrid>
 </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel> 
 </Grid>    
     </StackPanel>        
     </ScrollViewer>
```

LeftComboItems, RightComboItems are Observable Collections of type string.

Comment: What do you mean by _not visible_? Content is not visible or scrollbars? If scrollbars where do you put your `SomeView` control? Is it within `Grid`, `StackPanel` or something else?

Comment: @dkozl I have posted my entire xaml. Scrollbars are not visible. Particularly the vertical one.

Comment: How do you use it then? What's the container for it? Is it something like `<StackPanel><local:SomeView ... /></StackPanel>`?

Comment: @dkozl I guess you are right. I think you should rewrite this as an answer.

Comment: @dkozl I am using a usercontrol instead of a page or a window. Scrollviewer is directly inside the usercontrol. <UserControl><Scrollviewer> </ScrollViewer></UserControl>

Comment: @dkozl <Window> <ScrollViewer><Grid></Grid></ScrollViewer></Window works for other screen but, <UserControl><ScrollViewer><Grid><StackPanel></StackPanel></Grid?</ScrollViewer></UserControl> doesn't work

Comment: @user2951819 I can see how you define it. I want to know how you use it. You must put it in some container like `Page` or `Window`, potentially with other controls. How do you do it? If this container in which you put your `UserControl` when you use it gives it infinite height, like `StackPanel`, then you won't see scroll bar

Comment: @dkozl <Window><Grid><ItemsControl><UserControl></UserControl></ItemsControl></Grid></Window>

Comment: @dkozl I am using PRISM pattern.

Comment: @dkozl Height and Width of the window are both 300

Comment: If you use it in `ItemsControl` then it will give each item as much space as it needs so you'll not see scrollbar. Did you try setting `Height` on your `UserControl`?

Comment: @dkozl No I didn't will do it and update  you about the result. Thanks

Comment: @dkozl I can't do that. It spoils the look and feel. Also Setting HorizontaolScrrollBarVisibility="Auto" adds an extra empty column in each of the datagrids inside the grid.

Comment: So, as far as I understand, your problem is not related to `UserControl` at all. You want to see scrollbar for the whole `ItemsControl` content (you have more items then you can see) where `UserControl` is just an item. Correct? If yes then you don't need `ScrollViewer` inside `UserControl` instead of that put whole `ItemsControl` within `ScollViewer` like so: `<ScrollViewer ...><ItemsControl>....</ItemsControl></ScrollViewer>'. `ItemsControl` does not support scrolling by default

Comment: @dkozl I am using PRISM architecture. I am loading my view a usercontrol inside the ItemsControl of the Shell window. It contains only my usercontrol. I want to enable horizontal and vertical scrolling.

Comment: I don't know PRISM but you must have some view that says you want to use `ItemsControl` to display list of your `UserControls`. In that place just say that `ItemsControl` should be contained within `ScrollViewer`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the StackPanel (use Grid/Panel) or set some large height for StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the ScrollViewer control is used to enable scrolling in overflow situations like in a  ListBox with many items for example. So if I where you I would put the DataGrid in a ScrollViewer and remove any fixed Row heights to let it overflow otherwise there is no point in using the ScrollViewer.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have not mention any where the height and width of your screen. Scroll viewer displays
after a specific limit. So if you want scroll viewer to get displayed mention at least minimum height for the case of vertical scroll bar. when your data/controls in that scroll viewer exceeds the limit of height it will appear.

```
ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MinHeight="300" MinWidth="200"
```